# Vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector

What exactly is happening when you enter

for example,

x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7] and
y = [7 6 5 4 3 2 1]

**x(y)** into MATLAB

what is the function taking place between x and y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It treats the values in `y` as indices, and prints the `x` values at those indices.  In other words:

```
x(y) = [x(y(1)) x(y(2)) ... x(y(7))]

x(y) = [x(7) x(6) ... x(1)]

x(y) = [7 6 5 4 3 2 1]
```

In this case, that happens to be the same as your `y` vector, but if you change around some values in `x` or `y`, you can see how it effects your output.